# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

The Workplace's [eighth moderator election](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/8) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the two new moderators are:

[image: motosubatsu] [image: Kilisi]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/8), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5692008124383232/0).

Comment: Congratulations and welcome to the team!

Comment: Well done chaps! A nicely diverse set of mods!

Comment: Congratulations to the "winners".  I know that both mods will do their very best to be fair and keep a calm head.

Comment: Welcome to the Team, guys!

Comment: Thank you gentlemen :-) And Mari-Lou ;)

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Congratulations and good luck both. 8-)

Comment: Congratulations, as @Snow already mentioned a diverse and well balanced mix ;)

Comment: Congrats to both new mods. I don't think we would have gone wrong with any of the candidates, but you were both in my top three. Also, good job keeping your votes secret everyone who voted for @Kilisi Making him think he was only going to get a couple votes made his win a bit more dramatic ;)

Comment: I voted for Moto and Snow, seemed a bit unsporting to vote for Kilisi since we're relatives on my mothers side ;) but que sera sera, he squeaked in anyway.

Comment: Godspeed to those elected. I saw I gave you a run for your money though! XD